# Guardar y descargar archivo PDF con FPDF

Tags: php, ajax, fpdf

Compañeros, nuevamente recurro a su ayuda a ver si me pueden ayudar.

Estoy generado un botón con el ID de un campo de una tabla que corresponde a una orden de pedido de la siguiente manera:

```
<td width="15px" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="?pdf='.$id.'" class="pdf hint--bottom-left hint--rounded hint--info" aria-label="Descargar pdf"><i class="icon-file-pdf-o"></i></a></td>
```

Lo que quiero es que al dar click en ese link, me genere un archivo pdf, me lo guarde en el servidor y al mismo tiempo me lo descargue. Decidi hacerlo a través de AJAX, de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pdf', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = href.slice(href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    pdfs = vars.pdf;//Acá capturo el ID de la OP
    var dataStringS = 'canal=' + canal + '&userid=' + userid + '&user_final=' + user_final + '&val=' + pdfs;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "orden_pedido_generar_pdf.php",
        cache:false,
        data: dataStringS,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".loader").fadeIn("slow");
        },
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data)
        },
        error: function(jqXHR3, textStatus3, errorThrown3) {
            Swal.fire({icon: 'error',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Se produjo el error: ' + jqXHR3.status + '-' + textStatus3 + ' al generar el pdf de la OP',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 2000});
        },
        complete: function(xhr3) {
            $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Ahora desde el archivo orden_pedido_generar_pdf.php, genero el archivo

```
 $pdf->Output();
 $pdf->Output('F','ruta/'archivo.pdf');
```

Con la anterior, me lo generar y guarda en el servidor sin problemas pero no logro que me lo descargue, en otra repuesta de esta misma página, informan que haga:

```
 $pdf->Output('FI','ruta/'archivo.pdf');
```

Pero no me funciona, su ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el método Output() de la clase FPDF genera el archivo PDF en la memoria del servidor. Para descargarlo, necesitas usar el método stream().

En el archivo orden_pedido_generar_pdf.php, cambia el código del método Output() de la siguiente manera:

```
$pdf->stream('archivo.pdf');
```

Esto generará el archivo PDF en la memoria del servidor y lo abrirá en una nueva pestaña del navegador.

También puedes usar el método save() para guardar el archivo PDF en el disco. En este caso, el código sería el siguiente:

```
$pdf->save('ruta/archivo.pdf');
```

Esto guardará el archivo PDF en la ruta especificada.

Para que el archivo PDF se descargue automáticamente, puedes usar el método download(). En este caso, el código sería el siguiente:

```
$pdf->download('archivo.pdf');
```

Esto generará un encabezado HTTP que indicará al navegador que descargue el archivo PDF.

En tu caso, puedes usar el método download() para descargar el archivo PDF automáticamente. El código sería el siguiente:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pdf', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = href.slice(href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    pdfs = vars.pdf;//Acá capturo el ID de la OP
    var dataStringS = 'canal=' + canal + '&userid=' + userid + '&user_final=' + user_final + '&val=' + pdfs;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "orden_pedido_generar_pdf.php",
        cache:false,
        data: dataStringS,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".loader").fadeIn("slow");
        },
        success: function(data){
            //alert(data)
            $pdf = new FPDF();
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
            $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Orden de pedido',0,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(40,10,'ID: '+pdfs,0,0,'C');
            $pdf->Ln(20);
            //Aquí va el código para generar el PDF
            $pdf->Output('F','archivo.pdf');
            $pdf->download('archivo.pdf');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR3, textStatus3, errorThrown3) {
            Swal.fire({icon: 'error',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Se produjo el error: ' + jqXHR3.status + '-' + textStatus3 + ' al generar el pdf de la OP',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 2000});
        },
        complete: function(xhr3) {
            $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias @Londoño pero lamentablemente no me funcionó. Lo que hice fue que desde el archivo orden_pedido_generar_pdf.php generé el pdf y lo guardé en el servidor. Luego envíe la ruta al AJAX y desde allí con una etiqueta  simule un click el cual me descargue. No sé si sea estético hacerlo así, pero de otra manera no lo pude hacer. Dejo el código AJAX como quedó:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pdf', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = href.slice(href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    pdfs = vars.pdf;//Se captura el ID de la OP
    //Se prepara el AJAX para generar el pdf
    var dataStringS = 'canal=' + canal + '&userid=' + userid + '&user_final=' + user_final + '&val=' + pdfs;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "orden_pedido_generar_pdf.php",
        data: dataStringS,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".loader").fadeIn("slow");
        },
        success: function(data){
            if (data.validar==1){//Se generó el PDF correctamente
                ruta = data.ruta;//Se captura la ruta
                $('#dpdf').attr('href', ruta);//Se asigna la ruta a la etiqueta "a"
                //Crear el evento user-click            
                var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
                    view: window,
                    bubbles: true,
                    cancelable: true
                });
                //Obtener el objetivo de nuestro user-click
                var objetivoDelClick = document.getElementById('dpdf'); 
                objetivoDelClick.dispatchEvent(event);//Realizar evento
                            
            }else{
                Swal.fire({icon: 'error',title: 'AVISO',html: data.mensaje,showConfirmButton: false,timer: 2000});
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR3, textStatus3, errorThrown3) {
            Swal.fire({icon: 'error',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Se produjo el error: ' + jqXHR3.status + '-' + textStatus3 + ' al guardar los valores de la OP',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 2000});
        },
        complete: function(xhr3) {
            $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
});
```